# rabbitmq cluster how to change active/active into active/passive mode?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have setp a 2 nodes rabbitmq cluster with one loader balancer at frontend, after this was setup, it was working as active/active mode, then network partition happened on one node, I got the failed node out of the cluster and rejoin it into the cluster again, then this failed node were not accecpting any connection.

Then I tried to moved the other node out of the balancer, the recovered node began to accept connections, so this cluster is active/passive mode.

I don't know what caused this, is there any way to change it back to active/active? And which step to specify its mode during setup?

Thanks for your advice in advance!

Answer (score 0):

rabbitmq really (really) doesn't like network partitions.  By default, when you have one, everything pauses.  In that situation you must fix it manually.  Choosing the loser by stopping it and starting it should resume everything once it rejoins the cluster.

If that doesn't work, then shut down the failed node, and use rabbitmqctl to "forget_cluster_node", and then rejoin it to the cluster.

You should read this very carefully
https://www.rabbitmq.com/partitions.html
specifically, "Recovering from a network partition"

Then read the next few paragraphs even more carefully.  There are some automatic recovery modes, each with advantages and disadvantages.

At my company we chose autoheal because we value availability, and accept the possible loss of messages.